# In a metric space, prove there is an invertible function $\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^n$ such that $f(a)=b$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I would like to prove the following theorem from Mendelson's Introduction to Topology:

> For each $a,b\in\Bbb R^n$, prove that there is a topological equivalence between $(\Bbb R^{n},d)$ and itself defined by inverse functions $f\colon\Bbb R^n\longrightarrow\Bbb R^n$ and $g\colon\Bbb R^n\longrightarrow\Bbb R^n$ such that $f(a)=b$. [Hint: If $a=(a_{1}, a_{2}, ..., a_{n}), b = (b_{1}, b_{2}, ..., b_{n})$, define $f$ by setting $f(x_{1}, x_{2}, ..., x_{n}) = (x_{1}+b_{1}-a_{1}, ..., x_{n}+b_{n}-a_{n})$.]

I'm not totally certain what is meant by $(\Bbb R^n,d)$ since the text has somewhat ambiguously used this notation to sometimes specifically mean that $d(a,b) = \max{|b_{i}-a_{i}|}_{i\leq n}$, and then sometimes used this to mean any unspecified distance metric.  I've been trying to prove it for an unspecified distance metric, which might be the problem here.

What I've done so far:  Trivially, this definition of $f$ makes $g(x_{1}, ..., x_{n})=(x_{1}-b_{1}+a_{1}, ..., x_{n}-b_{n}+a_{n})$ an inverse.  Let $\delta_{1}=d(a,b), \quad \delta_{2}=d(f(a),f(b))=\left( (b_{1}, ..., b_{n}), (2b_{1}-a_{1}, ..., 2b_{n}-a_{n})\right)$.  To prove topological equivalence from the definition would be to prove that $f$ and $g$ are continuous.

So let $\varepsilon>0,\quad x\in\Bbb R^n$ be given.  We want to find a neighborhood of $x$ such that $y\in B(x,\delta)$ implies $d(f(x),f(y))<\varepsilon$.  At this point I've just been trying to wrangle $d(f(x),f(y))$ by Algebra to get into a format where I could constrain $x,y$ by some amount and get the desired result.  My Algebra so far:

For easy notation, let $(x_{1}+b_{1}-a_{1}, ..., x_{n}+b_{n}-a_{n})$ be written $x+b-a$, for instance.  Then

$d(f(x),f(y)) = d(x+b-a, y+b-a) \leq d(x+b-a, y) + d(y, y+b-a) \leq d(y, x) + d(x, x+b-a) + d(y,y+b-a)$.

At this point I don't see where to go from here.

Comment: For an arbitrary metric, the statement is wrong: View $\mathbb R^n$ as subspace of $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ in the obvious way, except that you map $a$ to $(a_1,\ldots,a_n,1)$ instead of $(a_1,\ldots,a_n,0)$. Then endow $\mathbb R^n$ with the metric inherited from the standard metric on $\mathbb R^{n+1}$. With this metric, $a$ is an isolated point (and the only isolated point) of $\mathbb R^n$. -- You should assume the standard metric.

Comment: $f(x)=x+b-a$ is an isometry and hence a homeomorphism, under the standard metric.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, I'm a little confused--are you saying that, for certain distance metrics, $(\mathbb{R}^{n}, d)$ will not be topologically equivalent to itself?  Or are you instead saying that for certain distance metrics, you can find certain $a,b\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that there is no invertible function $f(a)=b$ which entails the equivalence?  I guess I'm confused because the function you gave, mapping in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ seems like it doesn't use the same distance metric inside of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ before and after the mapping.

Comment: I mean the latter. The point really is that $d(a,x)>1$ for all $x\ne a$, whereas we cannot have $d(f(a),f(x))>1$ for all $x\ne a$, i.e. there is no homeomorphism $f$ as required with $f(a)=b$ (especially: the metric I exhibited is not translation invariant).

Answer (score 0):

I assume that $d$ is the metric induced by a norm, as usual in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then $d(f(x),f(y))=d(x+b-a,y+b-a)=d(x,y)$ since norms are invariant under translation.

Comment: Is the theorem not true for a general distance metric?  It kind of seems like it should be--at least, in general, every topological space should be equivalent to itself.  Is it that not every topological space is provably equivalent to itself using an invertible function $f$ such that $f(a)=b$ for any $a,b\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ that you select?

Comment: I am not sure that you can always construct a topological equivalence with a prescribed value at a prescribed point. It looks like the typical case where the topology is invariant under translation (as in topological vector spaces as $\mathbb{R}^n$ is).